# How to export animation from Figma to Lottie format?

Tags: animation, lottie, figma

I want to make loader, and designer send it to me in Figma's Json, but l want to convert it into Lottie-available json animation.

Maybe you know some ways how to do it right with myself or with designer help?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Lottie is built for use with AfterEffects, not Figma.